# Enumitem always throwing errors

Tags: enumitem

I have a very basic question. I am using LateX now for quite a while but haven't managed to use the package enumitem since it always clashes with my existing enumerate environments that are already in the document (I am just starring again at the following error message, after yet another attempt to use the package:

```
"..Undefined control sequence. \enit@endenumerate -> \enit@after \endlist \ifx\enit@series\relax \else \if ... l.376 \end{enumerate}"
```

I have had this problem across different versions of LateX and different Laptops. What do I need to change in order to get enumitem to work ?

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Please post a small example that shows the problem. The error message above has been reformatted so I am not even sure which command is undefined as the original linebreak has been lost.

Answer (score 14):

I have located the problem. It seems that "enumitem" clashes with the package "paralist" which was sitting on every preamble since I've started using LateX.

(Many thanks for reminding me that minimal examples are required, that helped me to find the cause myself).

Comment: Might be worth noting that this error only occurs if on use `enumitem,paralist` but not if loaded as `paralist,enumitem`.

Comment: Same error if you load enumerate and enumitem together

Comment: @Cedric it makes no sense to load `enumerate` and `enumitem` together. They both define `\begin{enumerate}` which can only have one definition. Just use `enumitem`.