# NewDocumentCommand enumerate macro not working with linebreak while \newcommand does work

Tags: macros, enumerate, xparse

In the following code, I write two macros for `\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}`. In trying to get more than one optional argument, I used the method in [More than one optional argument for newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29973/more-than-one-optional-argument-for-newcommand). However, when I add an extra linebreak between `\item`s, the `\NewDocumentCommand` macro fails while the original `\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}` is fine, and `\newcommand` macro is also fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

% if do enumitem before enumerate, cause error????? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238691/enumitem-always-throwing-errors
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


\newcommand{\myenumerate}[2][4]{\begin{enumerate}[(a), leftmargin=0.2in,parsep=0pt,itemsep=#1pt]
#2
\end{enumerate}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myenumeratebad}{ O{10} O{a} m }{\begin{enumerate}[(#2),leftmargin=0.3in,parsep=0pt,itemsep=#1pt,topsep=8pt]
#3
\end{enumerate}}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(i),leftmargin=0.3in,parsep=0pt,itemsep=4pt,topsep=8pt]
\item awef

\item awef
\end{enumerate}

\myenumerate[10]{
\item awe

\item awf
}

\myenumeratebad[10][i]{
\item awe
\item awf
}

\myenumeratebad[10][i]{
\item awe
\item awf
}

\end{document}
```

P.S. in making my MWE, there was an issue putting `enumitem` before `enumerate`, but not the other way around. I only learned about this from a comment here [Enumitem always throwing errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238691/enumitem-always-throwing-errors).

Comment: you can not use enumerate and enumiten  at the same time you are using enumitem here so delete the enumerate package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think if I delete the enumerate package I lose the ability to write [(a)] or [(i)] to specify what type of bullet points I want

Comment: No you do not: you are not using `enumerate` at all. If you have two packages one does `\def\qqq{a}` the other does `\def\qqq{b}`  then you can not load both packages and have `\qqq` magically be `a` and `b` at the same time. You load `enumitem` second so it wins  and loading `enumerate` first just makes things slower.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok I see, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `\newcommand` creates a macro that is defined *long*, i.e. accepting paragraph parameters, i.e. an empty line. (A *short* macro uses `\newcommand*`.)

With `\NewDocumentCommand` all paramaters are by default short – unless the argment is prefixed by a `+`. (Yes, you can specify the *length* on an “argument-by-argument basis”, page 3 of the [`xparse` manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/xparse/0).)

So, you're going to need

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\myenumeratebad}{ O{10} O{a} +m }{%
  \begin{enumerate}[(#2),leftmargin=0.3in,parsep=0pt,itemsep=#1pt,topsep=8pt]
  #3
  \end{enumerate}}
```

---

Though, you might just define your own environment again:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenumerateenv}{O{10} O{a}}{%
  \begin{enumerate}[(#2),leftmargin=0.3in,parsep=0pt,itemsep=#1pt,topsep=8pt]}
  {\end{enumerate}}
```

which you can use with or without empty lines.

```
\begin{myenumerateenv}[10][i]
\item awe

\item awf
\end{myenumerateenv}
```